# How to calculate numpy array without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcast

I have two numpy arrays with shapes `A = (226, 250)` and `B = (195, 195, 250)`. I want to compute a new array `C`:

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    C = A[i, :].reshape(1, 1, -1) - B
```

Is there another way to calculate C without an iteration process?

Comment: Shrink the dimensions down  to 4x5 and 3x3x5. Hard code example input and result arrays

Comment: also, you're overwriting C with each iteration. What are the dimensions of your desired output?

Comment: I omitted process after C.
The A and B array data type is float16 and I'm struggling with inefficiency of iteration. :(
Sorry that I'm not good at English.

Comment: What result do you want?  In your loop `C` is (195,195,250), but you don't accumulate the values in the loop.  Do you want a (226,195,195,250) result?  Try reshape to (226,1,1,250).

Comment: Correctly what I wanted!
I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want

```
C = A[:, None, None, :] - B
```

`None` is an alias for `np.newaxis`. It inserts a new axis in the location you place it in the index. Just like

```
C = A.reshape(A.shape[0], 1, 1, A.shape[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `apply_along_axis`

```
C = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.reshape(1, 1, -1) - B, 1, A)
```

But keep in mind that the whole dataset is processed in the ram. This may cause an RAM issue.

Edit:
The solution with  `C = A[:, None, None, :] - B` has the same issue with the RAM.

An alternative way could be to hold the loop and use a [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) decorator. This will fasten up the loop to nearly c speed and avoid flooding your RAM.